# Allow user to access by ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Hi all I have an Ubuntu server with some users.
My user can access in ftp to this server and see all folder.
I have added an existing user to the group ftp but when he log into the ftp client he can only see an empty folder I think is /home/user that is empty.

How can I change the folder when he log into ftp client?
Because when I login into the ftp client I am into the root directory and can see all.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set their base directory in /etc/passwd. If you want to limit them to certain areas, this is also the file you'll need to edit to change their shell type.

Comment: I have aleady set it like /home/user but when I log in if I click to go up of a level nothing happen like I can't exit from this folder

Comment: Change the path to "/" then.